# What is the point of the string.Empty property

Tags: c#

Why was the property `string foo = string.Empty` included in the BCL? It seems more verbose and no clearer than just using an empty string (`string foo = ""`)

Comment: Nitpick: It is not part of the language. It is part of the BCL. VB.NET and F# can use it, as well as every other .NET language.

Comment: Oded: Nitpick noted and corrected :)

Comment: Because otherwise, you couldn't do evil things like `typeof(string).GetField("Empty").SetValue(null, " ");` ;)

Comment: @MasonWheeler: You can? :O :O I would hope that would throw a `FieldAccessException`.

Comment: @MasonWheeler - The joys of reflection. For real evil, you need introspection, eh?

Comment: @Steven: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: @MasonWheeler, +1. Oh god, the goggles, they do nothing!]

Comment: @Oded for a double nitpick, the preferred term is FCL these days, rather than BCL ;)

Comment: @MasonWheeler That is pure, distilled evil. I love this. Question if you're interested: wouldn't it be safer (and decently performant) to have written it as `public static string Empty { get { return string.Intern(""); } }`?

Comment: @MasonWheeler never mind the phrase "decently performant" above. Actual testing shows otherwise: 50x slower.

Comment: @MasonWheeler as of today it doesn't work anymore :)

Comment: @newfal: Really? What happens now?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I can only assume here:

`string.Empty` has been defined for explicitness - when initializing a string, it may not be clear from context that `""` was indeed explicitly meant as an initializer (instead of `null` or say `" "` or just as a place holder during testing). Using `string.Empty` is a definite answer to that sort of conundrum.

It may also be a throwback to C - an empty string in C is not an empty string. It is a character array whose first character is null (hence, empty), which is not the same as C#. My point here being that in different languages you would represent an empty string in different ways (and they may have different meanings) - having a `string.Empty` precludes such ambiguity.

As opposed to what others say about multiple objects - this is not a problem as any string literal will get interned on compilation. This includes the value of `string.Empty` - `""`. Any time either of these are repeated in code, the object will be retrieved from the intern pool. This is true *per app domain*.

Comment: +1 for being the only correct answer so far.

Comment: Some languages might not even *have* an empty string literal.  Apparently, standard [Pascal](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/bwk-on-pascal.html) didn't.

Comment: "an empty string in C is not an empty string" — but still, if you write `""`, you get `{'\0'}`, so there would be no difference between an empty string literal and some other roundabout way of defining it.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not 100% sure of the sources where I learned these, but some of the points for using it include:

- Each string in a .NET assembly is unique, so having

  ```
  string foo = "";
  string bar = "";
  ```

  results in 2 strings in the output assembly since strings are immutable.  Having both reference `string.Empty` reduces assembly size.
- Explicitness.  When you come across `string.Empty` the intent is clear that it's supposed to be an empty string.  But if you come across `foo = ""` did the programmer remove the contents of the string while testing and forget to add it back, or is it supposed to be that way?

Comment: It would seem to be an odd behavior for it to keep two identical strings in memory. Is that in fact what is done?

Comment: In fact, the opposite is done - it's called string interning (more precisely, interning of literals). I know for sure it's done in Java and Python, and I'm pretty sure it's the case in .NET languages too. Of course, it can only happen at the scope of a single translation unit, so unless the dynamic loader unifies such data, you may end up with one empty string per program file. Still not terribly much.

Comment: +1 for 2nd point. In fact it is better than creating a separate constant and naming it something different by each developer. COBOL used this long time ago.

Comment: @delnan is absolutely right. `""` / `string.Empty` are interned and only **one** object will be created.

Comment: @delnan in a simple test, String.Empty is the same as "", so they're definitely unified (though this may be a special case)

Comment: @Random832 Did you make sure to check for reference equality? .NET overloads the `==` operator for System.String so you need to run `object.ReferenceEquals("", string.Empty)` to properly test it. Using this shows they are the same reference, which makes sense since .NET interns strings just like Java and Python.

Comment: @DanHerbert I used `(object)"" == (object)String.Empty`, and the IL output shows a `ceq` instruction.

Comment: @Agent_9191  This is false.  All strings are interned, the compiler I believe ensures that each unique string references the same immutable value.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning

Comment: @Andy - All string _literals_ are interned in .NET. Not _all_ strings. Programmatically created strings do not get interned by default. See [String.Intern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: @Oded, true, thanks for clarifying.  In the context of string.Empty and "" however they both are the same interned string, except as pointed out in that MSDN article.

Comment: @Oded et alia: Actually none of you are exactly right. First, literals are interned *within an assembly* but not necessarily *across assemblies*. Second, whether or not the empty string is interned across assemblies is an implementation detail; some versions of the CLR do and some do not. There's a link to my article about this fact in one of the other answers; see it for the details.

Answer (score 2):

No object will be created for `string.Empty`.  Using `""` will create an object that will most likely come from the string intern pool.

In the past, people have run tests and `String.Empty` comes out slightly faster, but its a micro-optimization.

String.Empty is this:

```
//The Empty constant holds the empty string value.   
//We need to call the String constructor so that the compiler doesn't mark 
//this as a literal.   
//Marking this as a literal would mean that it doesn't show up as a field 
//which we can access from native.  
public static readonly String Empty = "";
```

Comment: So your point is... ?

Comment: The point is String.Empty is basically a constant for "".  Find the author of String.cs for a deeper meaning. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of optimization of memory consumption and an optimization of string comparison. Every time you're using an empty string in your application, you are allocating a string object containing 0 characters. As for string comparison it can be done by comparing references (pointers) instead of character by character, which is a faster even for empty strings.

If you are using many times the same string in your application you can use the same kind of mechanism by calling String.Intern() with your string. But if you are using each string only once, then you'll only use more memory.

So String.Empty is only a special case optimization which is worth to do for most .Net applications, that's why it was integrated in the BCL.

For more detail on this subject I strongly recommend reading [Eric Lippert's blog post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/string-interning-and-string-empty).

You should also take a look at [this documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.intern?view=net-5.0) referenced by his blog post.

Comment: Link only answers don't make good answers. If Eric ever reorganises his blog this answer will become useless. Please **summarise** the post here so we have all the information to hand.

Comment: @ChrisF: I can't ever reorganize the blog. That would be a breaking change, and you know how I feel about those.

Comment: @EricLippert - I realise that *you'd* never do that, however, link only answers aren't good answers and we need to encourage people to realise that.

Comment: @EricLippert It's not just about ephemeral links. It's also about politeness to readers here, there should be at least enough content directly in the answer so that readers can form an opinion as to whether to follow the link. And the answer should make sense even in an offline copy of SE.